# errror XA9008: Building from the command-line requires a Business License on cloned repo

Tags: git, xamarin, msbuild

I'm currently working on a Xamarin Android project on Windows using an indie licence. when pushing to git I clone the repo to run a build (using a git pre-push hook).

I do that to make sure the commit contains all the files necessary to build.

Doing that I get an error:

> error XA9008: Building from the command-line requires a Business License

If I run the same build command on the original location (where i develop using Xamarin Studio) it works file.

So I wonder how Xamarin determines the licence and what file the clone is missing to run the build. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Is your git hook using a different login user to build with?

Comment: @SushiHangover No, I push using the same account and don't do anything special in the scripts so I think the build runs using the same account.

Comment: msbuild-based headless builds are a business license feature. How do you currently build your original repo from the cli (before your git hook build routine is invoked (msbuild/xbuild/mdtool)

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for your help. I now saw on the Xamarin page that headless builds is part of what they call "Business Features" and therefore only available with the business licence. What i don't understand - i can run the headless build in my default working directory - but in a cloned repo (git clone ./ ./test) it does not work anymore.

Comment: Stupid me. It worked on the original repo because there were no changes on the source and therefore the build did not run. After running "clean solution" it also failed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SushiHangover mentioned in a comment: msbuild-based headless builds a part of what Xamarin calls "Business Features" and therefore only available with the business licence. See https://store.xamarin.com/ for more information

Comment: Is this still true given that Microsoft has opened up the Xamarin licensing?

Comment: "4.0.3.214 resolved this. I believe it had something to do with the changes to the licensing models" https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=35894#c29