# Building from the command-line requires a Business license

Tags: xamarin.ios, mono

I am trying to install xamarin forms app into actual iphone device. but after loading signing identity and provisioning profile, when it runs I am getting 
"Building from the command-line requires a Business license." error.

Comment: What version of Xamarin.iOS do you have installed?

Comment: I have this version 
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   12.2.1.12 (65ec520)

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482274/errror-xa9008-building-from-the-command-line-requires-a-business-license-on-clo/34514135) to see if it helps.